# Spying on immutable native methods

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, spy

I want to test if `window.location.assign` is being called, and so am trying to use `spyOn(window.location, 'assign');`, but the method isn't overwriteable.

Are there any other approaches I can use to spy on native methods that can't be overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to create a wrapper of the immutable function in your class:

```
MyClass.prototype.locationAssign = function () {
    window.location.assign.apply(window.location, arguments);
}
```

and spy on that method.

```
spyOn(MyClass, 'locationAssign');
```